How can avoid nested forEach loops for this tabbed content script?
I have made a small script in JavaScript for tabbed content.


(function() {
  let contentElms = document.querySelectorAll('.content > div');
  let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li');

  // Show first tab initially
  contentElms[0].classList.add("active");
  tabs.forEach((tab, index) => {
    tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // Toggle tabs
      tabs.forEach((tab) => {
        tab.classList.remove("active")
      });
      tab.classList.add("active");

      // Toggle content
      contentElms.forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.remove("active")
      });

      contentElms[index].classList.add("active");
    });
  });
})();
body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
 body * {
     box-sizing: content-box;
}
 .tabbed-content {
     max-width: 600px;
     margin: 10px auto;
}
 .tabbed-content .tabs ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     display: flex;
}
 .tabbed-content .tabs ul li {
     flex: 1;
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .tabbed-content .tabs ul li.active {
     border-bottom: none;
     font-weight: bold;
}
 .tabbed-content .tabs ul a {
     display: block;
     padding: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #7f7f7f;
}
 .tabbed-content .content {
     padding: 10px;
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     border-top: none;
     border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
 .tabbed-content .content > div {
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 1.5;
     text-align: justify;
     display: none;
}
 .tabbed-content .content > div.active {
     display: block;
}
 
<div class="tabbed-content">
  <nav class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Nesciunt velit a hic, officia animi veritatis quis obcaecati tempora omnis iusto.</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias dolorem, sequi quos unde tempora corporis voluptatibus officia atque voluptatum consequuntur necessitatibus fuga quidem nihil. Perspiciatis reiciendis impedit cupiditate odit veritatis!</div>
    <div>Deserunt est in, ipsum possimus dolorum! Numquam suscipit laborum, reiciendis delectus. Labore?</div>
  </div>
</div>



The tabs work fine.
The problem
I am unhappy with the fact that there are nested forEach loops in the script.
Questions

Is there any (reliable) way to avoid that?
Can I have just one forEach loop in the script?


Yes, no loops at all is needed. Use event delegation and store the current active tab into a variable.

Which nested loops bother you? The top level loop just assigns click handler for each tab. Each click handler has no nested loops, just two top level loops to set the active class.

@WiktorZychla Can I have just one forEach loop in the script?

Yeah. You can use this code
Instead of loops we will save references to active content and tab elements and update them on click


(function() {
  let contentElms = document.querySelectorAll('.content > div');
  let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li');

  // Show first tab initially
  contentElms[0].classList.add("active");
  tabs[0].classList.add("active");
  let contentActive = contentElms[0]
  let tabActive = tabs[0]
  tabs.forEach((tab, index) => {
    tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
      contentActive.classList.remove("active")
      contentActive = contentElms[index]
      contentActive.classList.add("active")

      tabActive.classList.remove("active")
      tabActive = tab
      tabActive.classList.add("active")
    });
  });
})();
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.tabbed-content {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.tabbed-content .tabs ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.tabbed-content .tabs ul li {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tabbed-content .tabs ul li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tabbed-content .tabs ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7f7f7f;
}

.tabbed-content .content {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.tabbed-content .content>div {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: justify;
  display: none;
}

.tabbed-content .content>div.active {
  display: block;
}
<div class="tabbed-content">
  <nav class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Nesciunt velit a hic, officia animi veritatis quis obcaecati tempora omnis iusto.</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias dolorem, sequi quos unde tempora corporis voluptatibus officia atque voluptatum consequuntur necessitatibus fuga quidem nihil. Perspiciatis reiciendis impedit cupiditate odit veritatis!</div>
    <div>Deserunt est in, ipsum possimus dolorum! Numquam suscipit laborum, reiciendis delectus. Labore?</div>
  </div>
</div>




It does not add/remove the class "active" on tabs.

Would like to explain your code little bit to let the OP where he did wrong?

@RazvanZamfir it will do it

As mentioned in comments, you can use the event delegation, to achieve the desired result.


(function() {
  let contentElms = document.querySelectorAll('.content > div');
  let tabsContainer = document.querySelector('.tabs');

  // Show first tab initially
  contentElms[0].classList.add("active");
  tabsContainer.querySelector('li').classList.add("active");

  // Use event delegation
  tabsContainer.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    let tab = event.target.closest('li');
    
    if (tab) {
      let index = Array.from(tabsContainer.querySelectorAll('li')).indexOf(tab);

      // Remove active class from all tabs and content
      tabsContainer.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove("active"));
      contentElms.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("active"));

      // Add active class to the clicked tab and corresponding content
      tab.classList.add("active");
      contentElms[index].classList.add("active");
    }
  });
})();
body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
 body * {
     box-sizing: content-box;
}
 .tabbed-content {
     max-width: 600px;
     margin: 10px auto;
}
 .tabbed-content .tabs ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     display: flex;
}
 .tabbed-content .tabs ul li {
     flex: 1;
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .tabbed-content .tabs ul li.active {
     border-bottom: none;
     font-weight: bold;
}
 .tabbed-content .tabs ul a {
     display: block;
     padding: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #7f7f7f;
}
 .tabbed-content .content {
     padding: 10px;
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     border-top: none;
     border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
 .tabbed-content .content > div {
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 1.5;
     text-align: justify;
     display: none;
}
 .tabbed-content .content > div.active {
     display: block;
}
<div class="tabbed-content">
  <nav class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Nesciunt velit a hic, officia animi veritatis quis obcaecati tempora omnis iusto.</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias dolorem, sequi quos unde tempora corporis voluptatibus officia atque voluptatum consequuntur necessitatibus fuga quidem nihil. Perspiciatis reiciendis impedit cupiditate odit veritatis!</div>
    <div>Deserunt est in, ipsum possimus dolorum! Numquam suscipit laborum, reiciendis delectus. Labore?</div>
  </div>
</div>



So, the tabsContainer (which is the parent of all tabs) listens for click events. When a click happens, it checks if the target (event.target) is a tab (li). Then the index of the clicked tab is determined by converting the NodeList of tabs into an array with Array.from and using indexOf to find the index. Lastly, all tabs and content elements have the active class removed first. Then, the clicked tab and the corresponding content are set to active.

I'm not sure which one is faster, either mine or the answer posted above, but I assume both options will give same result. If you care about time complexity, you need to check which one runs faster.

"time complexity"??? Really? Do you expect millions of tabs?

@jabaa sorry, but as a person who has masters in AI, I do care about time complexity of everything. :)

In cases with small n, the time complexity doesn't matter. A worse time complexity can be faster than a better time complexity.

Here is another variant of event delegation.
Personally I think the code is no more complex than attaching events directly to each element, but one massive advantage of event delegation is that it also works with dynamic content, eg. If later a tab is added dynamically you don't need to do anything else.


const content = document.querySelector('.tabbed-content');

content.addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
  const contentElms = content.querySelectorAll('.content > div');
  const tabs = content.querySelectorAll('.tabs li');
  const clickedTab = e.target.closest('li');
  if (clickedTab) {
    for (let ix = 0; ix < contentElms.length; ix ++) {
      const active = tabs[ix] === clickedTab;
      contentElms[ix].classList.toggle('active', active);
      tabs[ix].classList.toggle('active', active);
    }
  }    
});
body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
 body * {
     box-sizing: content-box;
}
 .tabbed-content {
     max-width: 600px;
     margin: 10px auto;
}
 .tabbed-content .tabs ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     display: flex;
}
 .tabbed-content .tabs ul li {
     flex: 1;
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .tabbed-content .tabs ul li.active {
     border-bottom: none;
     font-weight: bold;
}
 .tabbed-content .tabs ul a {
     display: block;
     padding: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #7f7f7f;
}
 .tabbed-content .content {
     padding: 10px;
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     border-top: none;
     border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
 .tabbed-content .content > div {
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 1.5;
     text-align: justify;
     display: none;
}
 .tabbed-content .content > div.active {
     display: block;
}
<div class="tabbed-content">
  <nav class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="active">Nesciunt velit a hic, officia animi veritatis quis obcaecati tempora omnis iusto.</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias dolorem, sequi quos unde tempora corporis voluptatibus officia atque voluptatum consequuntur necessitatibus fuga quidem nihil. Perspiciatis reiciendis impedit cupiditate odit veritatis!</div>
    <div>Deserunt est in, ipsum possimus dolorum! Numquam suscipit laborum, reiciendis delectus. Labore?</div>
  </div>
</div>




Really nice, short script. :)
